# Selenium : Admin should be able to log into the Magento Admin backend successfully

Tags: magento2, testing, docker, mftf, selenium

I'm trying to run functional tests on my magento project following this [tutorial](https://devdocs.magento.com/mftf/docs/getting-started.html)
i'm using selenium docker image by running this command :

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 --shm-size 2g selenium/standalone-chrome:3.9.1
```

and when i try running an example test `vendor/bin/mftf run:test AdminLoginSuccessfulTest --remove`

I get this error :  `Fail  Field by name, label, CSS or XPath element with '#username' was not found.`

and when i checked the screenshot provided by selenium i get 127.0.0.1 refused to connect
[image]

I don't how to fix it and allow it to access 127.0.0.1
and while looking for an error i found this under dev/tests/accesptance/tests/_output/allure-results this error

> Test
> filesvendor/magento/module-backend/Test/Mftf/Test/AdminLoginSuccessfulTest.xml
> ]]>
>
> Field by name, label, CSS or XPath element with '#username' was not found.
> #0 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/module-webdriver/src/Codeception/Module/WebDriver.php(1201):
> Codeception\Module\WebDriver->findFields()
> #1 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/module-webdriver/src/Codeception/Module/WebDriver.php(1746):
> Codeception\Module\WebDriver->findField()
> #2 [internal function]: Codeception\Module\WebDriver->fillField()
> #3 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Step.php(268):
> call_user_func_array()
> #4 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Scenario.php(76):
> Codeception\Step->run()
> #5 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework/src/Magento/FunctionalTestingFramework/_generated/AcceptanceTesterActions.php(1874):
> Codeception\Scenario->runStep()
> #6 /var/www/html/tajerpro/dev/tests/acceptance/tests/functional/Magento/_generated/default/AdminLoginSuccessfulTestCest.php(37):
> Magento\FunctionalTestingFramework\AcceptanceTester->fillField()
> #7 [internal function]: Magento\AcceptanceTest_default\Backend\AdminLoginSuccessfulTestCest->AdminLoginSuccessfulTest()
> #8 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Lib/Di.php(128):
> ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs()
> #9 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Cest.php(138):
> Codeception\Lib\Di->injectDependencies()
> #10 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Cest.php(150):
> Codeception\Test\Cest->invoke()
> #11 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Cest.php(82):
> Codeception\Test\Cest->executeTestMethod()
> #12 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Test/Test.php(98):
> Codeception\Test\Cest->test()
> #13 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php(639):
> Codeception\Test\Test->run()
> #14 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/phpunit-wrapper/src/Runner.php(117):
> PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite->run()
> #15 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/SuiteManager.php(161):
> Codeception\PHPUnit\Runner->doEnhancedRun()
> #16 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php(208):
> Codeception\SuiteManager->run()
> #17 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Codecept.php(162):
> Codeception\Codecept->runSuite()
> #18 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Command/Run.php(401):
> Codeception\Codecept->run()
> #19 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255):
> Codeception\Command\Run->execute()
> #20 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009):
> Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
> #21 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273):
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
> #22 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(149):
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
> #23 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/src/Codeception/Application.php(117):
> Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
> #24 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/app.php(46): Codeception\Application->run()
> #25 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/app.php(47): {closure}()
> #26 /var/www/html/tajerpro/vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept(7): require('/var/www/html/t...')
> #27 {main}

Is having selenium and my web driver is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

seems to be both issues are different.

1. Username not found &
2. 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

check your files where you have define the URLs to replace 127.0.0.1 with domain you want. this is actually hitting your local server.